# WCF Data Service not returning detailed errors

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, client-side

I configured my WCF Data Service this way:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
      config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
```

In the HandleException method I set this:

```
 protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
    {
      args.UseVerboseErrors = true;
```

I added this attribute to my service class:

```
  [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
  public class InformationService: DataService<InformationEntities>
```

On the client side (Android) I get this message from the server:

```
An error occurred while processing this request.
```

Where is the detailed exception? What else should I set?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding this to your WCF service code at the startup on the host. It causes exception details to be included in faults that are thrown to, and caught by, the client. Without this, details of the exceptions are hidden.

And make sure that, when you're catching those internal exceptions, that you throw a generic "fault" object to the client using the WCF System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException object. Dot NET exceptions are Microsoft centric, so if you're throwing errors to non-MS devices like Android or iPhone, you need to use the CommunicationObjectFaultedException.

```
ServiceDebugBehavior debug = ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
if (debug == null) {
    ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior {     IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
} else {
    if (!debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults) {
        debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my Service is attributed by this: [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
  public class InformationService : DataService<InformationEntities>, so your suggestion is already set. I use the HandleException method to catch exceptions and I throw nothing, just log the error that is automatically thrown to the client, so basically the original error is returned to the client.

Comment: Understood. When you figure out the problem, post it for others.